# Less css: 'calc(x+y)' outputs 'calc(z)' instead of just 'z'

Tags: less

I have the following css rule:

```
@somevar = 8px
.someclass { width: calc(8px + @somevar); }
```

After processing (lessc 2.7.1) it outputs:

```
.someclass { width: calc(16px); }
```

But the 'calc()' operation is ignored by older browsers and it's obviously not needed here because there is nothing to be calculated.

So how do I get it to output

```
.someclass { width: 16px; }
```

Comment: `just do x+y` ...

Comment: Huh that works? Lol well i have some ctrl-f-ing to do :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want `calc` to appear in your output, don't include it in the input.

As pointed out in comments, `calc` is not needed for the less compiler, it's a css function.

So this will work:

```
@somevar: 16px;
.someclass { width: 16px + @somevar; }
```

outputs:

```
.someclass { width: 32px; }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that `calc` is part of CSS, not of less.